# Java Producer-Consumer: producer does not "notify()" the consumer

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a producer - consumer problem with one producer and one consumer. The producer can not create more than five products. The consumer can not consume a product if there is no.

I am locking them both on a field called "monitor", when needed.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ConsumerProducer {

private static final Object monitor = new Object();
private final int MAX_PRODUCTS = 5;
private String[] products = new String[MAX_PRODUCTS];

int slotToProduce = 0;
int slotToConsume = 0;

private Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer());
private Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer());

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private synchronized void produce() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            // Acquiring access to produce a product
            while (slotToProduce - slotToConsume == MAX_PRODUCTS) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

            // Producing a product
            System.out.println("Will now produce product " + slotToProduce);
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            products[slotToProduce % MAX_PRODUCTS] = "Teddy Bear "
                    + Integer.toString(slotToProduce);
            System.out.println("Successfully produced product "
                    + products[slotToProduce % MAX_PRODUCTS]);
            slotToProduce++;

            // Notifying consumers if there were no products before
            if (slotToProduce - slotToConsume == 1) {
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            produce();
        }
    }

}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private synchronized void consume() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            // Acquiring access to consume a product
            while (slotToProduce == slotToConsume) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

            // Consuming a product
            System.out.println("Will now consume product "
                    + products[slotToConsume % MAX_PRODUCTS]);
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully consumed product "
                    + products[slotToConsume % MAX_PRODUCTS]);
            slotToConsume++;

            // Notifying producers if before there were no spaces to produce
            // a product
            if (slotToProduce - slotToConsume == MAX_PRODUCTS - 1) {
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            consume();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    final ConsumerProducer cp = new ConsumerProducer();
    cp.producer.start();
    cp.consumer.start();
}
```

}

However, when I run my program, the output is:

- Will now produce product 0
- Successfully produced product Teddy Bear 0
- Will now produce product 1
- Successfully produced product Teddy Bear 1
- Will now produce product 2
- Successfully produced product Teddy Bear 2
- Will now produce product 3
- Successfully produced product Teddy Bear 3
- Will now produce product 4
- Successfully produced product Teddy Bear 4

and from here on the program halts.

So the question is: even if I synchronize both consumer and producer on the same object "monitor", why the consumer stays asleep all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are synchonizing on monitor object. But you invoke sleep and notify on the producer and consumer object.

required changes:

1. invoke wait(), notify() on monitor
2. remove synchonized on methods. Leave only sync on monitor object.
3. never ignore interrupted exceptions!
4. think about using queue. Look at interface java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue